# Contar palabras repetidas en subarreglos

Tags: javascript

La funcion llamada 'cuantosRepetidos' recibe como argumento un array de arrays llamado 'array' y un string llamado 'elemento'
Cada subarray contiene strings.Debe devolver la cantidad de veces que 'elemento' se repite dentro de los subarrays.

```
  // Ej:
  // cuantosRepetidos([['manzana', 'naranja'],['sandia', 'pera'],['uva', 'manzana']], 'manzana') debe retornar 2
  // ya que 'manzana' se repite 2 veces.
  // Nota: Podes usar for loops anidados.
```

Yo hice esto:

```
function cuantosRepetidos(array, elemento) {
var contador = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (var elemento of array) {
      if (array[i] === elemento) {
        contador++
      }
    }

  }
  return contador;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El principal problema es que llamas `elemento` a la variable a buscar, pero también a cada variable de cada bucle interno `for (var elemento of array) {`.
Además el for of deberías hacerlo sobre array[i]:

```js
arr = [['manzana', 'naranja'],['sandia', 'pera'],['uva', 'manzana']];
function cuantosRepetidos(array, elemento) {//Aquí le llamo elemento
    var contador = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for(item of array[i]){/*Aquí le llamo item para no pisar la variable,
 además hago el loop sobre array[i]!*/
            if(item === elemento){
                contador++;
            }
        }
    }
    return contador;
}
console.log(cuantosRepetidos(arr, 'manzana'));
```

Comment: por qué array[i]

Comment: Porque usas un bucle for i=0;i<array.length para recorrer el primer array (que en este caso contiene 3 arrays dentro), si no usas array[i] siempre estarás trabajando sobre el mismo elemento.